# Is it possible to anonymously call API App and it automatically redirect the browser to AD Login page?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-apps, azure-api-management

During the recent Microsoft Cloud roadshow in London, something that came out of one of the talks on App Service was using AAD B2C for authentication.

It is possible currently to add Azure AD as an authentication for an API App:

[image]

Calling this API app from a browser based web app with no authorization header results in a 302 redirect immediately followed by a 401 response.

It was mentioned at the cloud event that it would be possible to call an API app anonymously from a web app, and have the azure App service handle the redirection to the AAD login page, get the token on successful login and then pass the call on to the API app and return the data.

However, I am struggling to see how this can be achieved without any responsibility on the calling web app to handle the redirect. Normally you would handle a 401 response from an API by obtaining a bearer token via AAD on the client side and sending it through as the authorisation header with the api request.

I have been through numerous examples on the Azure site and others and all of them are handling the logon/obtaining the token in the client web app.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Hi Declan, can you clarify your setup?  How is your web API being called?  Is it being called by a browser or is it being called by some backend code in your web app?

Comment: I have an API App in Azure which I have imported into API management. I am calling the API management uri for the api (which looks like http://MyApiManagement.azure-api.net/MyApi) from a C# WebClient within a Web App. I get back the 302 redirect response where the API is redirecting to the AAD login page, but how should I proceed from there? Thanks

Comment: I don't see how that is possible.  I think the redirect response from your WebClient would have to be manually propagated back to the client using the response from your MVC controller.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** I just realized (as pointed out by @Darrel-Miller that you don't really want to allow the user to put the credentials in.

The only thing that is still unclear to me, is where do you want to provide the credentials for AAD?, What is it exactly what you would like to accomplish.

Even more, why would you use AAD if there no user interaction at all.
If all that you want is a secure connection you can just use the standard application key for the web api without enabling AAD. And its as pretty straight forward to just add the MS_ApplicationKey to your header and you are good to go.

As you described in your comment you have a webclient that tries to do the requests and gets the 302, that is why my original answer wast that you would use ADAL. But now that I get deeper into what you want probably what you want to use is KurveJS :
https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/kurvejs

And it has the AAD app model v2 with Active Directoy B2C.

This makes it easy to add third party identity providers such as Facebook and signup/signin/profile edit experiences using AD B2C policies

You can read more about it here:
https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/kurvejs/blob/master/docs/B2C/intro.md

---

Do you mean this??
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn463788.aspx

Just use ADAL nuget package to handle the call...

You can read this from the post:

As soon as the execution hits the call to AcquireToken, you’ll get the authentication dialog shown in Figure 8. ADAL takes care of contacting the right endpoint and rendering the authentication experience provided by the server in a pop-up dialog without requiring you to write any UI code.

I hope this works for you!

Comment: The OP is trying to call the API from within the web app on the server.  Popping up a dialog there is probably not a good idea.